# Setting up Selenium Firefox profile

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Running our tests, we encountered a problem related to the way FireFox manages the events when the browser doesn't have the focus.

We found out that this problem can be solved setting up a FireFox profile with the preference "focusmanager.testmode" set to true (https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/157).

My question is, do you know of any other preference/capability/whatever that is worth having in our profile/configuration of the webdriver?

This could save us a lot of time in the future debugging strange problems/behaviours and I'd really appreciate any advise that you could give me.

Comment: To be honest I'm quite anti- having a set of custom preferences/profile-settings: (a) to minimise differences between what's tested and what a regular user would see, (b) to minimise browser-specific code. I'm all for FF bugs getting fixed and default behaviour changing, rather than people picking different workarounds. In other words, I'd like Firefox to be a black box.

Comment: @AndrewRegan could you give your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow-up my comment, I'm quite anti- having a set of custom preferences / profile-settings:

- to minimise differences between what's tested and what a regular user would see
- to minimise browser-specific code
- plus it can make diagnosing problems on sites like this more complex

In other words, I'd like Firefox (et al) to be a black box.

I'm all for Firefox bugs getting fixed, and perhaps even the default behaviour evolving over time, providing everyone is "on the same page". I think testing is complicated enough without people picking different workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox has all sort of preferences that can be tweak to improve tests stability. But as pointed out by [Andrew Regan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519316/setting-up-selenium-firefox-profile#comment60651082_36519316) changing anything may affect your tests so, may be not a best idea.

Anyhow this is a set of prefs I use to make tests fail less often due to unexpected browser behaviour:

```
// Disable checking if firefox is default browser
lockPref('browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser', false);

// Disable restoring session
lockPref('browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash', false);

// Disable updater
lockPref("app.update.enabled", false);
// make absolutely sure it is really off
lockPref("app.update.auto", false);
lockPref("app.update.mode", 0);
lockPref("app.update.service.enabled", false);

// Prevent closing dialogs
lockPref("browser.showQuitWarning", false);
lockPref("browser.warnOnQuit", false);
lockPref("browser.tabs.warnOnClose", false);
lockPref("browser.tabs.warnOnCloseOtherTabs", false);

// Disable Add-ons compatibility checking
clearPref("extensions.lastAppVersion");

// Don't show 'know your rights' on first run
pref("browser.rights.3.shown", true);

//Disable plugin checking
lockPref("plugins.hide_infobar_for_outdated_plugin", true);
clearPref("plugins.update.url");

// Disable health reporter
lockPref("datareporting.healthreport.service.enabled", false);

// Disable all data upload (Telemetry and FHR)
lockPref("datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionEnabled", false);

// Disable crash reporter
lockPref("toolkit.crashreporter.enabled", false);
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/toolkit/crash-reporter;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsICrashReporter).submitReports = false;

// Browser Console command line
pref("devtools.chrome.enabled", true);
```

To automate the process of setting up prefs you may like to use so called Firefox autoconfig file.
Sample configuration: https://github.com/cliqz-oss/firefox-autoconfigs

Comment: We've decided to avoid tampering with the profile and go for Andrew Regan's solution. Thanks anyway.